# Feedback for variation of Nurikabe puzzle I made up

Tags: grid-deduction

Just in case you don't know how to solve a Nurikabe puzzle: see [this tutorial](https://www.logicgamesonline.com/nurikabe/tutorial.html).

Now, onto my puzzle. What I made was a variation of the Nurikabe puzzle. It's a clueless Nurikabe puzzle, so there is nothing on the grid.

[image: clueless nurikabe]

There are clues on the side to solve the puzzle.

> Size of island
>   (number)Blocks
>
> How many of that size islands
>   :(number)

The finished puzzle should have the "islands" and the "water".
It would be helpful if you gave me feedback. If you can solve the puzzle, that would be cool too.

Answer (score 7):

A logic puzzle should generally have one valid solution, and provide some sort of human-deducible path toward that solution. Here, any solution can always be mirrored or rotated to provide another valid solution. Apart from that, there seem to be multiple valid solutions here even without mirroring or rotating:

> [image]
>  [image]

Comment: Huh. I got a different solution than those.

Comment: @Northex Yes, that's a problem. As jafe said, logic puzzles should have a *single* solution, and that unique solution should be deducible from the given puzzle with pure logic. This doesn't satisfy that.